# Cannot Install Tensorflow on Mac with Python 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow by following the instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#common_installation_problems. Now I am at step 7:

> Optional. If Step 6 failed (typically because you invoked a pip version lower than 8.1), install TensorFlow in the active Virtualenv environment by issuing a command of the following format:

```
$ pip install --upgrade tfBinaryURL   # Python 2.7

 $ pip3 install --upgrade tfBinaryURL  # Python 3.n
```

where tfBinaryURL identifies the URL of the TensorFlow Python package. The appropriate value of tfBinaryURL depends on the operating system and Python version. Find the appropriate value for tfBinaryURL for your system here.

For example, if you are installing TensorFlow for macOS, Python 2.7, the command to install TensorFlow in the active Virtualenv is as follows:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade \
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

As I am using Mac and Python 2.7, I used this command:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade \
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

but then I ended up getting an error message:

> Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-install-cx8mykog/grpcio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-42j10q8x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-cx8mykog/grpcio/

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Do you try to install it with anaconda ? What's your approach for this ? Please edit your question. Do you create virtual environment or trying to install tensorflow natively with pip ?

Comment: Your title says 2.7, but the error code clearly says 3.7. Which one is it?

Comment: I am on step 7 in TensorFlow Installation Guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#common_installation_problems), with details: For example, if you are installing TensorFlow for macOS, Python 2.7, the command to install TensorFlow in the active Virtualenv is as follows:

 $ pip3 install --upgrade \
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: I try to install it using my Terminal with pip